# How to find out versions of dependencies used in compiled Cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova, reverse-engineering, versioning

Background: I have a Cordova app release binary (signed .apk for Android) which was built in an unknown build environment.  I have the source code; but I need to find out the version of every dependency that was actually used to build that apk.

Example: Which version of Cordova itself?  Which version of each plugin?  Which version of npm/nodejs?

How would I get this info from the apk?

(Note: Part of the reason is that if I just re-build this from source using whatever versions of plugins config.xml resolves to, it is buggy; the original is not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Cordova version and version of each plugin that you have installed but I am not sure about how to get the npm version.

If you have the apk then extract(rename the extension to .zip) it. To find

**Cordova version**

Open `cordova.js` in **`assets/www/cordova.js`**. you can find one statement like following

```
var PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL = '8.1.0';
```

In my case, the Cordova version is `8.1.0`.

**Installed plugin version**

Open `cordova_plugin.js` in **`assets/www/cordova_plugin.js`**

There you will find your plugins in

```
module.exports.metadata = {
...
}
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you! In your example cordova itself is 8.1.0.  Do you happen to know a way of checking the cordova-android version as well?

Comment: is it the android sdk version?

Comment: It's something like <engine name="android" spec="^8.1.0" /> in config.xml and "cordova-android": "^8.1.0" in package.json.  But it doesn't show up in assets/www/cordova_plugins.js, probably because a platform is not a plugin

Comment: Ah, actually I think PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL is the cordova-android platform version rather than the cordova (cli) version.  I'll check with a test app